# What does the SECONDS variable actually do?

Tags: bash, time

So, as the title suggest, I noticed this *weird* thing where `sleep` essentially `increment` the time you give it as argument. Example:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
SECONDS="1"
while true; do
    echo "hello" || true
    sleep "$SECONDS"
done
```

But admittedly, that was only because of me using the `$SECONDS` variable, instead of naming it differently...
From what i can see, all it does is output the clock's second? a bit like what date does I'm guessing.

But what does it actually do beside that? I don't think i saw anything about it in the Bash documentation nor ever saw it on any public script before.

Comment: It is not the clock's seconds -- i.e. it does not reset in the range {00..59}. If your placeholder `echo` was a task that ran for e.g. 7, 4 and 15 seconds on successive iterations, the following sleep commands would be respectively `sleep 8`, `sleep 20`, and `sleep 55`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [bash man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> SECONDS
>
> Each time this parameter is referenced, the number of seconds since shell invocation is returned.  If a value is assigned to SECONDS, the value returned upon  subsequent  references  is  the
> number of seconds since the assignment plus the value assigned.  If SECONDS is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

So by setting `SECONDS` to `1` you restart the counter which now starts from 1 and doubles with every iteration of the while loop because the `SECONDS` variable is incremented by the elapsed time, giving you a nice geometric sequence `sleep`.

```
+ SECONDS=1
+ true
+ echo hello
hello
+ sleep 1
+ true
+ echo hello
hello
+ sleep 2
+ true
+ echo hello
hello
+ sleep 4
+ true
+ echo hello
hello
...
```

Answer (score 4):

A typical use of SECONDS is to time out a long-running task. This is more accurate than counting loop iterations, because it avoids the drift causes by the time spent within the repeated task:

```
EXPIRED=$(( SECONDS + 5000 ))
while (( SECONDS < EXPIRED )); do
    #.. some repeated task.
    sleep 30
done
```

If you are doing such things, assigning to SECONDS anywhere in your script is unsafe -- best to keep all other intervals relative to the original start time. Alternatively, you can set SECONDS initially to be anything more useful to you, e.g. seconds since midnight of the current day, which would be helpful if you also wanted to sync the repeated task to the next whole time unit with `sleep $(( 60 - SECONDS % 60 ))`.

To initialise SECONDS to seconds-since-midnight, I discovered:

```
SECONDS=$(( $( date '+ 3600 * %H + 60 * %M + %S' ) ))
```

Subshells are rather special. They inherit their parent shell's SECONDS as an export, so they can change it (e.g. reset to zero), but the parent does not see those changes. Stand-alone shell scripts do start over from SECONDS=0.

Answer (score -2):

In this case `$SECONDS` is

1. a terrible variable name; makes it confusing with the Bash built-in "SECONDS".
2. is an argument to the command `sleep`.

The `sleep` command defaults to seconds. By assigning `SECONDS` a value of `1` then passing this to the `sleep` command, it pauses processing of the while loop for 1 second, then re-processes the loop, etc. until the condition is satisfied.

To test this just open a terminal and type `sleep 1` and hit `ENTER`. The shell will pause for 1 second and then return the cursor to you.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that too :). Guess using that variable with `sleep` could still be used for cases where one want an "incrementing" sleep time...The more you know!

Comment: No confusion with the name: it **is** the Bash build-in variable (unless you specifically `unset SECONDS`.